# How to round the sum of node values to 2 decimals?

Tags: xml, xslt, rounding

I'm creating pdf from xml and xslt files with Apache FOP 2.3.

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
    <operations>
        <operation>
            <sold>5800.00</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>422.92</sold>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <sold>0.00</sold>
        </operation>
    </operations>
</root>
```

In the xslt file I have the following line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(.//operation/sold[number(.) = .])"/>
```

This will calculate the sum of all `sold` elements, resulting in `11297.960000000001` (the correct result would be `11297.96`). I need it to be rounded to 2 decimals, like this: `11297.96`. Also if the if the second decimal is 0, I still want to display it, so if the sum was, for example `12.3`, I want `12.30` to appear.

Comment: Use the `format-number()` function: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#format-number

Comment: Depending on the XSLT version and processor you can avoid the double inaccuracy by summing decimals in XSLT/XPath 2 or later `sum(.//operation/sold/xs:decimal(.))`, for formatting any number as needed you can use `format-number` e.g. `format-number(sum(.//operation/sold/xs:decimal(.)), '0.00')`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. What difference dose it make to use the decimal(.)? What is the difference between the result of `format-number(sum(.//operation/sold/xs:decimal(.))` and `format-number(sum(.//operation/sold)`?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the XSLT version and processor you can avoid the double inaccuracy by summing decimals in XSLT/XPath 2 or later `sum(.//operation/sold/xs:decimal(.))`, for formatting any number as needed you can use `format-number` e.g. `format-number(sum(.//operation/sold/xs:decimal(.)), '0.00')`.

The `xs:decimal` data type offers a higher precision than the `xs:double` (respectively number in XPath 1) data type, the inaccuracy that you see is just how the IEEE defines the IEEE double-precision 64-bit floating point type that XSLT/XPath 2 and later inherit from the XSD schema language https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#double. You will find the same problem in other programming languages using that data type (e.g. Javascript http://jsfiddle.net/23g5wexz/).

The `sum(.//operation/sold)` will work with the `xs:double` data type (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-sum), if you know you use `format-number` anyway on the result it suffices to work with the default `xs:double` (I think that default is mainly used in XSLT/XPath 2 and later for backwards compatibility with XSLT/XPath where a single number data type exists that implements/follows the IEEE double-precision 64-bit floating point spec.).